# Relacionamento entre Tabelas semelhantes

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, relacionamento

Eu tenho uma estrutura de Banco de Dados Relacional. Vou exemplificar de forma mais resumida minhas tabelas:

**Tab_Cliente com os campos (ID, Nome, ETC...)**

**Tab_Empresa com os campos (ID, Nome, ETC...)**

**Tab_Imagem com os campos (ID, Data, ETC...)**

Eu gostaria de criar um relacionamento 1,N tanto da Tab_Cliente, como como a Tab_Empresa com a Tab_imagem

Pelo que eu sei, eu tenho que adicionar uma chave estrangeira na Tab_Imagem, certo?

Porém, eu preciso criar uma FK relacionada tanto para Tab_Cliente, quanto para Tab_Empresa, certo?

Ficaria algo tipo:

**Tab_Imagem com os campos (ID, Data, ETC..., fk_cliente, fk_empresa)**

Só que dessa forma, toda linha teria uma chave primária do usuário que inseriu, porém apenas um deles irá fazer isso e não os dois...

Eu pensei na possibilidade de criar algo tipo:

**Tab_Imagem com os campos (ID, Data, ETC..., fk_users)**

Dessa forma eu entendo que cada linha de Tab_Imagem irá guardar apenas a chave primária do usuário que inseriu a mesma, porém eu sei como eu faria para informar isso ao banco, porque até onde eu sei o código seria algo assim:

**FOREIGN KEY(fk_users) REFERENCES NOME_DA_TABELA (CHAVE_PRIMARIA)**

Comment: Uma chave estrangeira identifica univocamente uma linha de **uma** outra tabela, dessa forma ela não pode referenciar mais de uma tabela. Talvez o uso de particionamento possa ajuda-lo (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html) mas não há dados suficientes para uma conclusão.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tab_Imagem com os campos (ID, Data, ETC..., fk_cliente, fk_empresa)
>
> Só que dessa forma, toda linha teria uma chave primária do usuário que
> inseriu, porém apenas um deles irá fazer isso e não os dois...

Essa seria a forma mais simples, a tabela teria duas FK (*foreign keys*), mas que deveriam ser `NULL`, pois pode ter valor de uma ou outra, e ainda, poderia ter as duas preenchidas, isso seria possível?

Quanto a parte de *"toda linha teria uma chave primária do usuário que inseriu"* quer dizer que tem nessa tabela também uma FK com a tabela de users correto?

Agora a parte a seguir ficou confusa: *"eu entendo que cada linha de Tab_Imagem irá guardar apenas a chave primária do usuário que inseriu a mesma"*, precisa explicar melhor a relação do user com as tables de cliente e empresa.

Estou "supondo" que, um usuário insere uma imagem (tabela "Tab_Imagem") e informa a relação dela, com a tabela "Tab_Cliente" ou "Tab_Empresa", e o seu problema é se vincular a imagem a ambas as tabelas, não vai ter a chave do usuário que fez as duas ações, é isso? Seria como esse modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desculpe perguntar isso na resposta, mas seria péssimo fazer isso nos comments, se estiver errado eu edito a pergunta.

Mas nesse caso ou mesmo para outro problema, uma solução que iria resolver esses problemas seria fazer o relacionamento em novas tabelas, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso, a relação entre "imagem x cliente" e "imagem x empresa" ficam em tabelas separadas, não sendo necessário modificar a tabela "Tab_Imagem".
Veja que ainda tem o usuário na "Tab_Imagem". Se quiser saber o usuário quem relacionou com as outras tabelas, basta adicionar uma FK para "Tab_Users" em "Tab_Cliente_Imagem" e "Tab_Empresa_Imagem". Dessa forma, ficam separados os relacionamentos, e evita ter FK com valor `NULL` na tabela "Tab_Imagem"

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta. "Tab_Users" foi apenas um exemplo, ela não existe. O objetivo é que tanto o usuário cliente, como o usuário empresa possam armazenar dados na tabela Imagem. Como ambos são usuários, eu fiquei na dúvida de qual deles seria a FK da tabela Imagem

Comment: Eu gostei bastante do teu segundo exemplo, abriu um norte para eu pensar em como resolver isso, obrigado.

Comment: não esqueceça de votar caso a resposta tenha ajudado ou resolvido seu problema :)

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, tanto um cliente como uma empresa podem inserir imagens na tabela de imagens, mas somente um deles cada vez e não os dois ao mesmo tempo, certo?

Isso é um problema para o conceito de chave estrangeira, pois este conceito assume que sempre haverá o relacionamento entre uma tabela e a outra no qual a chave estrangeira de uma é igual à chave primária da outra, e essa alternância de tabelas não é permitida.

Isso sugere fortemente que a sua modelagem está errada e você vai precisar mudá-la.

Mas isso é outro problema, que envolve estudar modelagem de dados e aplicar ao seu cenário.

Comment: Exatamente @Piovezan, de fato eu preciso ler um pouco mais para refazer a modelagem do meu banco, obrigado.